# How to let jenkins know my service was restart success of fail

Tags: jenkins

I have a spring boot application on centos server and use a shell file to restart it.

jenkins version: `docker run -dp 8080:8080 --name jenkins jenkinsci/blueocean`

start-service.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo systemctl restart sb
```

In my `Jenkinsfile` i upload jar file to server and execute the `start-service.sh`, but jenkins seem dosen't know my java application restart success or fail.

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3-alpine'
                    args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
                sh 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.name | grep "^[^\\[]" > project-name'
                sh 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep "^[^\\[]" > project-ver'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            agent any
            environment {
                HOST = "${HEHU_HOST}"
                USER = "yunwei"
                DIR = "/www/java/sb-demo"
                VERSION_FILE = "${DIR}/version"
                CMD_SERVICE = "${DIR}/start-service.sh"
            }
            steps {
                sshagent (credentials: ['hehu']) {
                    sh '''
                        name=$(cat project-name)
                        ver=$(cat project-ver)
                        jarFile=${name}-${ver}.jar
                        scp target/${jarFile} ${USER}@${HOST}:${DIR}/${jarFile}
                        scp project-ver ${USER}@${HOST}:${VERSION_FILE}
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${USER} ${HOST} -a ${CMD_SERVICE}
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I deliberately let Java application go wrong, and systemctl restart is fail but jenkins stage is success.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test error");
//        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    String test() {
        return "furukawa nagisa\n";
    }
}
```

[image: systemctl restart fail]

[image: jenkins stage success]

---

Try Daniel Taub solution get syntax error.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            agent any
            steps {
                sshagent (credentials: ['hehu']) {
                    SH_SUCCESS = sh(
                        script: '''
                            ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l yunwei ${HEHU_HOST} -a /www/java/sb-demo/start-service.sh
                        ''',
                        returnStatus: true
                    ) == 0
                    echo '${SH_SUCCESS}'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 9: Expected a step @ line 9, column 21.
                       SH_SUCCESS = sh(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `sh` returned exit status code and fail the build manually if its error status.

For checking your exit code, Jenkins [support](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script) it that way

> **returnStatus** (optional)
> Normally, a script which exits with a nonzero status code will cause the step to fail with an exception. If this option is checked, the return value of the step will instead be the status code. You may then compare it to zero, for example.

```
script {
    SH_SUCCESS = sh (
            script: "your command",
            returnStatus: true
    ) == 0
}
```

To manually fail the build you have couple of options:

```
error('Fail my build!')
```

Or alternatively

```
currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
return
```

Comment: I have no idea how to get sh result, I try your solution but get syntax error, please check my question, I have update it.

Comment: In pipelined scripts you should pack it with script block, I've updated my answer

Comment: Ok, it worked. But `SH_SUCCESS` is `true`, it should `false`. I think `sytemctl restart` not wait for my application return, so this command will always return `true`?

Comment: you should try waitUntil https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#waituntil-wait-for-condition